# HTML5 slides [SCORM based CBT] not working in Chrome but works in FireFox / IE / Edge

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat7

LMS [VALAMIS] HTML5 based CBT's designed in Captivate (10) runs perfectly in FireFox / IE / Edge but when comes to Chrome it plays just portion of first slide [like 9-10 seconds] and then halts.

Browser Console depicts following:

```
*src = https://abc/xyz/learn-portlet/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2381591.mp3 error code = 4 n/w state = 3    CPM.js:370 
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: audio, currentTarget: audio, eventPhase: 2, …}

src = https://abc/xyz/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2538057.mp3 error code = 2 n/w state = 1                 CPM.js:370        
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: audio, currentTarget: audio, eventPhase: 2, …}*
```

same CBT when run in other browsers work perfectly. on the server side we have 
Apache HTTPD [acting as web server + SSL applied]  ---> Tomcat 7

When I remove Apache from front and it goes to direct Tomcat 7 then

1. CBT plays 3 slides perfectly [around 1.5 minute runs ] and then halts.
2. shows different Error in browser console

```
*GET http://abc:8080/learn-portlet/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2538057.mp3 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 206 (Partial Content)
:8080/learn-portlet/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2401874.mp3:1 

GET http://abc:8080/learn-portlet/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2401874.mp3 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 206 (Partial Content)
:8080/learn-portlet/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2538057.mp3:1 

GET http://abc:8080/learn-portlet/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2538057.mp3 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 206 (Partial Content)
:8080/learn-portlet/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2401874.mp3:1 

GET http://abc:8080/learn-portlet/SCORMData/data/1676/ar/2401874.mp3 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 206 (Partial Content)*
```

cannot find any related log on server side when this thing happen [neither in HTTPD nor in Tomcat]
my worry is if its partial content [not completed somehow] then why FF / IE / Edge are doing it fine.
suspect I feel is Chrome policies or restrictions. due to which I have added user interaction in start of CBT [so that audio gets permission to be played].

Still struggling.

Comment: I've tweaked your post slightly to make the error logs formatted as "code"; I'm not sure if the line breaks are right, though. You may want to [edit] your post further to make any formatting improvements you can; the easier it is to read, the more likely you are to get answers.

Comment: thanks @CurtJ.Sampson i have udpated the line breaks as well.

Comment: instead of Sending Status 206, I changed to send status 200 and updated the header to not include Content Length ------- this thing worked for me. resolved.
Idea got from this link
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1044